# How to get the second value from the sql result instead of first result

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an android application in which i have a list of datas loaded from database in which if i select a particular list item it should show the last two recent dates of the table for which i have used the below query in that i would like to get the second value instead of first one because the first date is same as the selected list item date can anyone tell me how to select the second value instead of first one .I have used string split to select the second value but if the result has only one row means it shows me error.

Table:

```
 private static final String BILL_ID = "billno";
private static final String BILL_DATE = "billdate";
private static final String BILL_FARMERNAME = "billfarmername";
private static final String BILL_MOBILENO = "mobileno";
private static final String BILL_PRODUCTTYPE = "producttype";
private static final String BILL_PRODUCTNO = "productcounts";
private static final String BILL_PRODUCTCOST = "productcost";
private static final String BILL_TOTALAMOUNT = "totalamount";
```

Query:

```
String selectquery = "SELECT billdate FROM billlabel WHERE mobileno = '" + bfarmermobno + "' AND billno <= '" + billnumber + "'  ORDER BY billdate DESC LIMIT 0,2";
```

Comment: Use `cursor.moveToLast()` and then read the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` for that.

e.g something *like* this (untested!):

```
"SELECT billdate FROM billlabel WHERE mobileno = '" + bfarmermobno + "' AND billno <= '" + billnumber + "'  ORDER BY billdate DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1";
```

These operations are specified like so:

```
LIMIT <count> OFFSET <skip>
```

`LIMIT` specifies the number of records that you want to limit by, whilst `OFFSET` specifies the offset which you want to start from when fetching results.